# Bind vue model to react value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vuejs2

I am currently trying to migrate a form based project from vue to react. The way I do it is to re-write every vue component in react, and then serve the react component into the form

In stead of the vue component we have the Vue react-wrapper component

```
 <react-wrapper :component="ReactInput" :handleChange="handleChange" :value="value" />
```

Which gets the `ReactInput` component, mounts it with `createRoot()` and forwards props to it

The implementation works fine, however, being inside a Vue form, I need to find a way to actually bind this react input value, to the vue one, so the form gets updated

Previously, the binding was done like this

```
<b-numberinput 
   v-model.number="value.value" 
   :disabled="isDisabled" 
   :controls="showControls"
 />
```

Now, inside the Vue `<script>` tag I have the `handleChange` function which is called whenever the ReactInput value changes, hoping to sync somehow with the Vue model

```
##VueComponent##
    private handleChange(val: string //val comes from ReactInput) {
      this.value = val // Would want something like this hoping to replicate the v-model.number="value.value" , but doesn't work
    }
```

Any idea how I can basically bind the `val` inside `handleChange` with my vue model?

Answer (score 0):

React does not have dual binding.

You have to specify both the `value`, pointing to a state holding the value and `onChange` handler, updating the state holding the value.

As a side note, I have no idea why the official React documentation recommends `onChange` handler instead of [`onInput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) handler which IMHO is a more appropriate candidate.

Relevant documentation: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable

---

In more detail:

```
const value = ref('')
```

becomes

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')
```

and

```html
<input v-model.number="value" />
```

becomes

```
<input 
  value={value}
  type="number"
  onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
```

Typically you'd write a separate function (`onChangeHandler`) instead of calling `setValue` directly from template, especially if you want to typecast the value or want to prevent default based on any type of validation.

Important notes:

- the parameter of the `onChange` handler is the native `event` parameter of the native [ChangeEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) (available as `$event` in a Vue template), so you have to extract the `value` yourself.
- `e.target.value` is a string, even when you have `type="number"` on the `<input />`. Remember to convert it to number when you want it as a number; e.g:

```
const numericValue = Number(value)
```

Comment: maybe they want as few updates as possible because the cost of updating react components is very high anyway